# Django split String from database

Tags: python, django, web

I try to split a String from a database (SQLite). The String has a linebreak \n and I want split it there in 2 parts. It works with a normal String for example text = "Hello \n World". But if I use the string from my database it doesn't work (the text is saved correctly with \n in the database!!)

My Code for getting the first part of the string:

```
from django import template
from products.models import News

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_first_title(id):
    search_value = "\n"
    news = News.objects.values('title')
   title = news.filter(pk=id)
   number = str(title).find(search_value)
   first_title = str(title)[0:number]
   return first_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_first_title(id):
   news = News.objects.get(pk=id)
   return news.title.split("\n")[0]
```

Although you should probably catch posible exceptions with:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_first_title(id):
   try:
       news = News.objects.get(pk=id)
       splitted_title = news.title.split("\n")
       if splitted_title:
          return splitted_title[0]
   except News.DoesNotExist:
       # raise exception or return None or something
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead of your code in the last 4 lines

```
title = news.filter(pk=id)
number = str(title).split(" ")
# number is a list of strings
print(number , len(number))
```

Comment: i don't want to split my text in a list of words... In my database I'have a text like "This is a text \n with a linebreak"... I want to split this string in 2 parts. The first part should be "This is a text" and the second part should be "with a linebreak"